# Change version of dependency defined by Graiils

Tags: gradle, grails, apache-commons

We are currently running Grails 3.3.10. We are running into an issue with the included version of the Apache commons-validator. Grails 3.3.10 seems to use version 1.5.1 of the commons-validator.

Ideally we would like to update only the commons-validator and not Grails, I can see that the most current version is 1.7.

Is it possible to override the version included by Grails?

It seems like if I include it in my `build.gradle` with `compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7'` it will be downloaded by Gradle but will just live alongside the 1.5.1 version. When I run my app locally it will still use the 1.5.1 version (verified with breakpoints in IntelliJ).

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tyrelhdependency

https://github.com/jeffbrown/tyrelhdependency/blob/fb2912ebbac7ef6db2ee9446709248d8c70f50e6/build.gradle#L76

```
compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7'
```

If you run the dependency report `gradlew dependencyReport` and then inspect `build/reports/project/dependencies.txt` you will see that `commons-validator` has been updated to 1.7.

If you build the `.war file` with `gradlew assemble` and inspect `build/libs/tyrelhdependency-0.1.war` you should see that only 1 version of the library is there.

Comment: Your project could having something unusual in it that calls for a different solution.  If you can share a sample which demonstrates both versions of the dependency being pulled in, that would likely be trivial to troubleshoot, but I think that behavior would require a bug in Gradle or something problematic having been added to the build config.  My guess is your IDE config is just out of date and that is why you are hitting a breakpoint in the "wrong" jar.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input. The issue seems to be with my local cache / IDE. When I built our app it contains the updated package as expected and looks to work fine in our preprod environment.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I believe you look for the classes that have that depency:

```
grails dependency-report > deprep.txt
```

and then search for 'commons-validator'. This will tell you which dependencies are using it.

Next remove dependency from these plugins in your build.gradle file under dependencies (ex):

```
compile 'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1', {
    exclude group:'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
}
```

THEN... you will need to add in the dependency for the version you want for 'commons-validator'.

Of course this is from memory so it may not be perfectly accurate. But try it and see.